# How can I Direct Video Upload to TikTok via API for Personal Use?

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

I'm integrating video uploads to TikTok in my personal project and trying to understand if I can use the API without publishing my app. I expect to authenticate only as myself and would prefer not to go through the process of making an app public just for this purpose.

Is there a way to accomplish uploads via the API as a developer or a similar approach that doesn't require a published app?

Thanks for any guidance!